# Asp.net mvc 2 validate user control

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I am developing a site that needs to have a small form repeated in a lot of pages. So I decided to create a user control (partial view) that has this form.

This form posts to an action, so I have:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<SampleProject.DoSomethingActionVM>" %>
<%= using(Html.BeginForm("DoSomethingAction", "Home")){ %>

    //Form stuff

<% } %>
```

So the action is

```
public ActionResult DoSomethingAction(DoSomethingActionVM model){
   if(!ModelState.IsValid){
         return View(); //HERE IS THE PROBLEM
   }

   //Do something
}
```

So, the problem comes when I want to validate the form. If the form is not valid, I dont know where to return as this user control is being used in many views... :(
I tried to use a hidden field in the user control that says what View to use... but this was a bad idea as I am using strongly typed views and I dont know what model to send.

What is the best way to validate forms that are inside user controls (partial views)?

Thank you all in advance. I will thank you even more if you can give me quick ideas as I need it for tomorrow work :)

Juan

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a Service layer that creates the validation for you instead of the user control?  [See my blog](http://dotnetblogger.com/post/2010/07/04/MVC2-Separating-Concerns-with-Service-and-Repository-Layers.aspx) for some more info.

Basically in your Service layer you create MetaData that attaches to the Class Object.  I have a LINQ to SQL Class called User, and my UserMetaData adds Validation Functionality to the class.

```
<MetadataType(GetType(UserMetaData))> _ 
Partial Public Class User 
    Public Property UserRegion As String 
    Public LastSeen As DateTime 
End Class 


Public Class UserMetaData 

    <DisplayName("name")> _ 
    <Required(ErrorMessage:="Username is required.")> _ 
    <StringLength(30, ErrorMessage:="Username cannot exceed 30 characters.")> _ 
    <RegularExpression("^\w{3,30}$", ErrorMessage:="Not a valid username.")> _ 
    Public Property UserName As String 

    <DisplayName("email")> _ 
    <StringLength(50, ErrorMessage:="Email Address cannot exceed 50 characters.")> _ 
    <RegularExpression("^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})$", ErrorMessage:="Not a valid email address.")> _ 
    Public Property Email As String 

    <DisplayName("website")> _ 
    <StringLength(256, ErrorMessage:="Web Address cannot exceed 256 characters.")> _ 
    <RegularExpression("^http(s?)\://[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(/\S*)?$", ErrorMessage:="Not a valid website address.")> _ 
    Public Property WebSite As String 

    <DisplayName("about")> _ 
    <StringLength(2000, ErrorMessage:="Profile cannot exceed 2000 characters.")> _ 
    Public Property About As String 

    <DisplayName("region")> _ 
    <Required(ErrorMessage:="Region is required.")> _ 
    Public Property UserRegion As Integer 

    <DisplayName("birthdate")> _ 
    <DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode:=True, ConvertEmptyStringToNull:=True, DataFormatString:="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")> _ 
    Public Property BirthDate As DateTime 

End Class
```

Then your validation is as easy as passing the `User` object to the View and then using the following for validation

```
    <%  
        Html.EnableClientValidation()  
        Using Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Users")  
    %>  
      <%-- Lot's more crap in here--%>  
           <tr>  
                <td>  
                    <%: Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.UserName)%></td>  
                <td class="full-width">  
                    <%: Html.TextBoxFor(Function(model) model.UserName) %>  
                    <%: Html.ValidationMessage("UserName", "*")%>  
                </td>  
            </tr>  
      <%-- Lot's more crap in here--%>  
    <% End Using%>  

<script src="../../Assets/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="../../Assets/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="../../Assets/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcValidation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

### EDIT:

Upon reading your "answer", I think I better understand your question.  Here's what I think your best option will be.

1. You need to create a custom ViewModal for the fields you want to send to the View.  In this ViewModal you want to create validation as I did above.
2. Then you need to create A view to send the ViewModel to and you need to structure your controller as follows

In your controller you send info to the View

```
Function Email() As ActionResult
    ''# do stuff to populate your viewmodel
    Return View(customViewModel)
End Function

<AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)> _
Function Email(ByVal customViewModel as MyCustomViewModel)
    If ModelState.IsValid Then
        ''# do your valid stuff
    Else
        Return View(customViewModel)
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: I edited my answer explaining a bit better (I hope) the problem. Thanks for everything ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could put the `<form>` outside the user control in the calling page.

Comment: I edited my answer explaining a bit better (I hope) the problem. (look at the last message). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your idea to pass some metadata to the action looks nice. 
You want to use the view but I would take the calling url.

This way you dont have to know view and model but can just redirect to the calling url. You will loose your ModelState.Errors this way, but you can solve this issues using TempData directly or the ModelStateToTempdata attribute of MVCContrib.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution...
Its to use ajax for posting the form inside the control, and have a javascript function that handles the response. So, in the action you chack if ModelState.IsValid, if its not valid you get the modelstate errors and put them in a JSON object and return it. 
If everything its ok, I needed to redirect to another page, so I return a JSON object with a redirect url.

This is the url of what give the basics to solve the problem: http://www.hightech.ir/SeeSharp/aspnet-validation-with-ajax-and-json

thanks to all for the responses!
Juan